# Error executing Scripted editor: "Error showing url: The specified location is not supported"

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following error when trying to open Scripted 0.3 from Springsource

`Error showing url: The specified location is not supported`

I'm using Kubuntu 12.10 64 bits and installed it using npm (`sudo npm install -g scripted`) with the following output:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/scripted
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/scripted
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine/0.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/enhanced-resolve/0.4.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser/1.7.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json5/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-static/0.5.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sockjs/0.3.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/when/1.6.1
npm http GET https://github.com/kdvolder/websocket-multiplex/archive/master.tar.gz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/enhanced-resolve/0.4.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser/1.7.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/json5/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-static/0.5.9
npm WARN node-static@0.5.9 dependencies field should be hash of <name>:<version-range> pairs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sockjs/0.3.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/2.5.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.9
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/when/1.6.1
npm http 200 https://github.com/kdvolder/websocket-multiplex/archive/master.tar.gz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/faye-websocket/0.4.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rbytes/0.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid/1.3.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/faye-websocket/0.4.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rbytes/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid/1.3.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/-/connect-1.9.2.tgz

> rbytes@0.0.2 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/scripted/node_modules/sockjs/node_modules/rbytes
> node-waf configure build

Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr 
'configure' finished successfully (0.104s)
Waf: Entering directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scripted/node_modules/sockjs/node_modules/rbytes/build'
[1/2] cxx: src/binding.cc -> build/Release/src/binding_1.o
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/-/connect-1.9.2.tgz
[2/2] cxx_link: build/Release/src/binding_1.o -> build/Release/binding.node
Waf: Leaving directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scripted/node_modules/sockjs/node_modules/rbytes/build'
'build' finished successfully (0.959s)
/usr/local/bin/scr -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/scripted/bin/scr
/usr/local/bin/scripted -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/scripted/bin/scripted
scripted@0.3.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/scripted 
├── amdefine@0.0.2
├── node-static@0.5.9
├── when@1.6.1
├── websocket-multiplex@0.1.0
├── enhanced-resolve@0.4.5
├── json5@0.1.0
├── formidable@1.0.9
├── htmlparser@1.7.6
├── sockjs@0.3.1 (node-uuid@1.3.3 faye-websocket@0.4.0 rbytes@0.0.2)
└── express@2.5.11
```

I can't find any log files at the moment, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the new version of npm installed or the old version that comes default with Kubuntu?

Comment: I guess it was the default Kubuntu version, however I don't even have that computer anymore